# How to: Generate XML file in Visual Studio 'debug' configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm working with Visual C# 2010 Express, building managed applications.

- In 'release' mode, Visual Studio generates an assembly (dll or exe) as well as an XML file containing assembly method comments.
- In 'debug' mode, it generates the assembly and a PDB file (containing debug information).

Since I build everything in debug mode, I want to know how I can also generate the XML file with the assembly and pdb. Why is it not generated ? Strange behavior, we always need comments...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable generation of the XML documentation file by open the Properties for your project and choosing the Build tab. If you set the Configuration to Debug you should be able to check the "XML Documentation file" checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked everything in the option panel but forgot to go to the Project properties (working with Netbeans and Visual Studio at the same time let you think that every option is located at the same place in every IDE).

Answer (score 2):

In MS VS 2010 development Environment, In the Build tab page, last section Output, there is a Check Box "XML documentation file". When you check it, the default path will be bin\{your project name}.XML